# Phoenix + React can't make HttpGet request

Tags: reactjs, elixir, phoenix-framework, http-get

I'm using Phoenix version 1.3 with React in my application and trying to make Get request:

```
httpGet('/api/v1/users')
   .then(function (data) {
     console.log("http get works!!!!");
   })
   .catch(function (error) {
     console.log("nope doesn't work");
   });
```

where httpGet is:

```
export function httpGet(url) {
   return fetch(url, {
     headers: buildHeaders(),
   })
   .then(parseJSON);
 }
```

parseJSON:

```
export function parseJSON(response) {
  return response.json();
}
```

buildHeaders():

```
const defaultHeaders = {
    Accept: 'application/json',
   'Content-Type': 'application/json',
};
function buildHeaders() {
  const authToken = localStorage.getItem('phoenixAuthToken');
  return { ...defaultHeaders, Authorization: authToken };
```

And this is my router:

```
defmodule App.Web.Router do
   use App.Web, :router

pipeline :browser do
   plug :accepts, ["html", "json"]
   plug :fetch_session
   plug :fetch_flash
   plug :protect_from_forgery
   plug :put_secure_browser_headers
end

pipeline :api do
   plug :accepts, ["json"]
   plug Guardian.Plug.VerifyHeader
   plug Guardian.Plug.LoadResource
end

scope "/", App.Web do
   pipe_through :browser # Use the default browser stack
   get "/*path", PageController, :index 
end

scope "/api", App.Web do
   pipe_through :api

  scope "/v1" do
     post "/users", UserController, :create
     get "/users", UserController, :index
  end
end
```

I keep getting error that my httpget request fails. So, my question is what is wrong with my router? Post, Delete request works. I beleive it has something to do with the router, but I've can't find the exact problem. Any help appreciated!

Edit: Response from the server I get:

```
[info] GET /api/v1/current_user
[debug] Processing with App.Web.PageController.index/2
   Parameters: %{"path" => ["api", "v1", "users"]}
Pipelines: [:browser]
[info] Sent 200 in 260µs
```

And Google Dev tools:

```
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK
Response Headers: Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8
```

Comment: Does the request hit your server? Is anything logged in the server logs? Is there any error in the browser console? You can see the exact request that was sent from the Network tab in Chrome Dev Tools.

Comment: Hey @Dogbert, I've added the responses. It returns that everything is correct, but the response is HTML type, I guess it should be JSON here?

Comment: Ah, try moving the first `scope do ... end` below the second one. It looks like your wildcard route is catching everything.

Comment: @Dogbert Damn, I see, now everything works properly. Thanks a lot man!! Have a great day!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your catch-all route `get "/*path"` is matching all GET requests, including the ones sent to `/api/v1/users` since it is present before the `/api/v1/users` route. If you move it below, everything should work as expected:

```
pipeline :browser do
   ...
end

pipeline :api do
   ...
end

scope "/api", App.Web do
  pipe_through :api

  scope "/v1" do
     post "/users", UserController, :create
     get "/users", UserController, :index
  end
end

scope "/", App.Web do
   pipe_through :browser # Use the default browser stack
   get "/*path", PageController, :index 
end
```

Comment: Thanks again! I didn't know that the order is important in the router.

Comment: Yes, routes are compiled into function clauses in the same order as they're declared, and so just like function clauses in Elixir, the first route that matches the request is used.